# How to convert the below string to list without using ready modules?

Tags: python, string, list

I need to convert this string `color ="['Red', 'Green', 'White']"` to a list without using **ready modules** such as (import ......).

The expected results: `color = ['Red', 'Green', 'White']`

Comment: @mshsayem in the link above there are also example without using ast or other import functions. You don't have to only focus on the accepted and top voted answers

Comment: Use `[i[1:-1] for i in color[1:-1].split(",")]`

Comment: Akshay - your answer produces - this answer: ['Red', "'Green", "'White"]

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Need to `strip()` also. There are spaces inside

Comment: @Boendal Yep! Missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
color = color[1:-1].split("'")
list_colors = []
for i in color:
    if len(i) > 2:
        list_colors.append(i)
print(list_colors)
```

that should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
>>> color ="['Red', 'Green', 'White']"
>>> color = [x.strip(" '") for x in color.strip('[]').split(',')]
>>> color
['Red', 'Green', 'White']
```